# How to define const in nodejs in global scope?

Tags: node.js

I want to separate my app in to the parts to have something like MVC... Currently I figured out `exports` works and how to communicate between different files. The one thing i cant understand is that how to use constants in global scope? Currently i have something like this:

```
// start.js

const ROOT_DIR = __dirname;
const APP_DIR = ROOT_DIR + '/app/';
const MODULES_DIR = '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/';
const APP_PORT = 4935;

var server = require(APP_DIR + 'server.js');

server.start();

// server.js

exports.start = function() {
    var express = require(MODULES_DIR + 'express'),
        app = express(),
        http = require('http'),
        server = http.createServer(app),
        io = require(MODULES_DIR + 'socket.io').listen(server),
        fs = require('fs'),
        path = require('path');

    server.listen(APP_PORT);

    app.use(express.static(ROOT_DIR + '/assets'));

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile(ROOT_DIR + '/views/index.html');
    });
}
```

Is it possible to automatically assign this constants to `server.js` or i need to pass them as variables?

Answer (score 18):

I think, you need create file with constants and use him as require file in begin a other module.

File consts.js

```
exports.CONST_1 = 42,
exports.CONST_2 = 123;
```

In the module where necessary:

```
var consts = require('path_to_consts.js');
var my_var = consts.CONST_1 + consts.CONST_2;
```

So all global variables will be in one place

Comment: Yes, but you need to understand that they are not global variables. Singleton pattern is maybe a better way to describe it.

Answer (score 3):

`Object.defineProperty(global, 'MY_CONST', { value : 123 })`

P.S. Please, don't do this

Comment: "P.S." part is awesome :D

Answer (score 1):

Javascript constants won't work globally across files in Node.js. You need to pass them to the function.

```
    // start.js

    const ROOT_DIR = __dirname;
    const APP_DIR = ROOT_DIR + '/app/';
    const MODULES_DIR = '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/';
    const APP_PORT = 4935;

    var server = require(APP_DIR + 'server.js');

    server.start(MODULES_DIR,APP_PORT,ROOT_DIR);

    // server.js

    exports.start = function(MODULES_DIR,APP_PORT,ROOT_DIR) {
        var express = require(MODULES_DIR + 'express'),
            app = express(),
            http = require('http'),
            server = http.createServer(app),
            io = require(MODULES_DIR + 'socket.io').listen(server),
            fs = require('fs'),
            path = require('path');

        server.listen(APP_PORT);

        app.use(express.static(ROOT_DIR + '/assets'));

        app.get('/', function (req, res) {
            res.sendfile(ROOT_DIR + '/views/index.html');
        });
    }
```

Comment: but id more like an argument rather than a function... As more i dive in nodejs, more i start to unlike it...

Comment: Export a variable means export a singleton, so you can require a module, change some values and when requiring again you will get the same object. It is just a design pattern, not a disadvantage of node.js or even any kind of programming language.

Answer (score 1):

This is method is same as suggested by @user3040347 but little different.

Here, you need create file with constants and use him as require file in begin of a module in which you want to use.

File consts.js

```
CONST_1 = 42,
CONST_2 = 123;
module.exports = {};
```

In the module where necessary:

```
var consts = require('path_to_consts.js');
var my_var = CONST_1 + CONST_2;
//Here you can access directly
```